# Spark --num-execotors options not clear

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, executor

I do not understand this option. It seems like its the maximum number of executors.

If there is not enough memory on the nodes in the cluster this number is doing nothing and there are fewer executors than I'm asking for.

Can someone clarify this please?

Answer (score 0):

The option `--num-executors` is used after we calculate the number of executors our infrastructure supports from the available memory on the worker nodes.
The calculation can be performed as stated [here](https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html). This wuill let you know the number of executors supported by your hadoop infrastructure or your the queue that has been assigned to your team.

Comment: That is not what I'm asking. I want to know if its a maximum or minimum of executors number

Comment: It is the maximum number of executors that you want for your job to run on the cluster. The above calculations let you get a number of executors that your cluster will accept

Comment: But why will I give a maximum number? I use the 'Dominante resource calculator' and dynamic allocation, I defined executor-cores and executor-memory. Isn't it (In this case) useless? I'm asking if --num-executors is useless in this case of course.